# Assembly understanding low and high bytes

Tags: assembly, avr

Good day,Could somebody explain to me how does this work?  I know that the total delay is 25.344 ms. But how do I count it? I know how to count the delay if I did not work with high and low bytes,but it seems I cannot get the right answer. Thank you.

```
 ;Delay Subroutine (25.351 ms) 
    delay:   in     save,SREG         ;Preserve status register 
             ldi    YH,high($18C0)    ;Load high byte of Y 
             ldi    YL,low($18C0)     ;Load low byte of Y 
    loop:    sbiw   Y,1               ;Decrement Y 
             brne   loop              ;and continue to decrement until Y=0 
             out    SREG,save         ;Restore Status register 
             ret                      ;Return
```

Comment: Seems to me like that depends on the frequency that your processor is clocked at, which you haven't specified in your question. Add up the cycles required for one `sbiw` and one `brne` (where the branch is taken), multiply that by `$18C0`, then multiply the result you got by the number of seconds per cycle.

Comment: This is basically a task, which we know that if it goes for example from 00 to FF it will take 255*768 with 2 loops. 1 MHz clock frequency. If we take the high byte which is 18 and low byte C0  it should be going from decimal 24 to 192 isnt it? end we will end up with 192*768*24?

Comment: `sbiw` operates on a 16-bit register pair. You've initialized the register pair `Y` (`YL` and `YH`) with the value `$18C0`, so that's how many times you'll loop.

Comment: We solved it. By multiplying '18C0' as decimal(6336) by 4 and we got the answer 25,351. Which is completely by accident.

Comment: Accident? `sbiw` and `brne` (when branching) are both specified as taking 2 cycles. Thus the loop takes 4 cycles per iteration.